# Is there a way to make an image ignore scrolling in a div without moving to a corner of the page?

Tags: html, image, position

I've been trying to make an update-log for a HTML page. The issue is, the job is to "make it look pretty" - an exact quote of what I've been asked.
They want a specific image in the corners of every single div, but I've hit an issue. Some of the divs scroll, in specific the update-log. Whenever I try to make the div scroll, the image sticks in one spot (image of explanation attached).
I'm trying to make it so the images stick to their corners regardless of scrolling, and don't move upon scroll. Is there a way to do this? CSS and HTMl is fine, I'm just meant to confine it to HTML for the project.

Edit: Forgot to say this, but whenever I use position-fixed it ends up going to the edges of the pages, not the div. This also has to be mobile-friendly preferably.

What it does:
[Link to image: mini-corner images scroll with the div.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EomLE.png)

What I need it should do (image edited via FireAlpaca, not what actually happens):
[Link to image: mini-corner images are not affected by scroll.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Jpu.jpg)

My current HTML & CSS code:

```css
.heightc {
    height: 460px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg heightc margin scroll inner" style="flex-grow: 3; border: 5px solid #acb2b5;">
    <img style="position: absolute; top: -1px; left: -1px; width: 50px; z-index: 1;" src="https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/images/51687767_YMNPzQqkmi2CP1H.png" alt="Top left corner">
    <img style="position: absolute; top: -1px; right: -1px; width: 50px; z-index: 1;" src="https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/images/51687774_ZWtici8CxHbaKAt.png" alt="Top right corner">
    <img style="position: absolute; bottom: -1px; left: -1px; width: 50px; z-index: 1;" src="https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/images/51687760_DcjvijLLUCRXi1e.png" alt="Bottom left corner">
    <img style="position: absolute; bottom: -1px; right: -1px; width: 50px; z-index: 1;" src="https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/images/51687807_VnKHqCyMkhDfhgf.png" alt="Bottom right corner">
    <p>
        <b style="padding: 5px;">22/05/22</b>
        <a href="https://toyhou.se/~world/74697.20studios">Updated: Alpha 0.1.3 Added all bases to base character gallery.</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

Write position:"relative" in the parent container.

```
/* Box C */
.heightc {
    height: 460px;
    position: relative;
}
```

HAving images positioned absolute and and parent contsainer position relative, the images will be positioned inside the parent's container's area

Comment: Still not working. The images still scroll with the div, when it's meant to stick to the corners.